# Quiero enviar datos a un formulario que esta en un modal atravez de ajax en laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

```
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach ($productos as $producto)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$producto->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->producto}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->precio}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->marca}}</td>
                                    <td>

                                        <a class="btn btn-primary"
                                           href=" {{url('producto.consulta/'.\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encrypt($producto->id))}}">
                                            <i class="fa  fa-search"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-primary"
                                           href=" {{url('producto.editar/'.\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encrypt($producto->id))}}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-danger"
                                           href=" {{url('producto.eliminar/'.\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encrypt($producto->id))}}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#modal-eliminar" onclick="submitt()" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-sm col-lg-offset-2 active"
                                        data-toggle="modal"
                                        > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

*aqui empieza mi ajax pero no se que error pueda tener me abre el modal 
pero sin los datos que estan en un datatable de jquery*

```
<script>
function submitt() {
$.ajaxSetup({
header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
});

$('#enviar').attr("disabled","disabled");
var url = 'producto.eliminar';
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
dataType:'html',
    json(),
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Te falto poner el metodo **json**

Comment: como lo podria realizar serias tan amable de explicarme mas o menos o ayudarme a integrarlo

Comment: El problema radica en que creo que te has planteado mal la solución de tu problema, cuando haces el foreach con laravel dentro d etu modal, no deberias hacerlo si el contenido lo vas a cargar por ajax, es decir deberias hacer el ajax y en el success del mismo agregarle las filas a tu tabla con los valores que traes de tu servidor